# How to create two controller with different table in zend 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

i want to create two controller with different tables fetch records then view,edit and update them my first album controller works fine but when i create another controller then it gives me error.

[image]

Comment: Could you post some of your code?

Comment: It looks from the error like you haven't set up your `Album\Model\DemoTable` in the service manager, see the tutorial on how it's done for the `Album\Model\AlbumTable` --> http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html#using-servicemanager-to-configure-the-table-gateway-and-inject-into-the-albumtable

Answer (score 1):

You need to register the service `Album\Model\DemoTable` with the service manager; just as you have with the existing `Album\Model\AlbumTable`.

The [documentation shows you how to register the `AlbumTable`](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-guide/database-and-models.html#using-servicemanager-to-configure-the-table-gateway-and-inject-into-the-albumtable);

So by modifying that example, something like this should work:

```
 // Module.php
 public function getServiceConfig()
 {
     return array(
         'factories' => array(
             'Album\Model\DemoTable' =>  function($sm) {
                 $tableGateway = $sm->get('DemoTableGateway');
                 $table = new DemoTable($tableGateway);
                 return $table;
             },
             'Album\Model\AlbumTable' =>  function($sm) {
                 $tableGateway = $sm->get('AlbumTableGateway');
                 $table = new AlbumTable($tableGateway);
                 return $table;
             },
             'AlbumTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                 $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                 $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                 $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Album());
                 return new TableGateway('album', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
             },
            'DemoTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                 $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                 $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                 $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Demo());
                 return new TableGateway('demo', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
             },
         ),
     );
 }
```

Obviously you will need to replace the `Demo()` class with the actual class that the table is mapping to.